# Problems running powershell command through bat file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, scripting

The command will run if placed straight into powershell, however if i try to run with the powershell -Command tag in a bat file i get the following error?

The command run is:

```
powershell -Command $tempFilePath = "$env:TEMP\$($filePath ^| Split-Path -Leaf)"
```

The error received is:

At line:1 char:26

```
+ $tempFilePath = $env:TEMP\$($filePath ^| Split-Path -Leaf)
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\$($filePath ^| Split-Path -Leaf)' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I would be grateful of any help, if you need any more information please ask. Thank you.

---

**Code from comment**

```
$filePath = 'filedir/file.conf.js'
$tempFilePath = "$env:TEMP\$($filePath | Split-Path -Leaf)"
$find = 'texttochange'
$replace = 'newtext'
(Get-Content -Path $filePath) -replace $find, $replace | Add-Content -Path $tempFilePath
Remove-Item -Path $filePath
Move-Item -Path $tempFilePath -Destination $filePath
```

The new error as outlined in comments:

```
Add-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '$env' does not exist.
At line:1 char:227
+ ... h) -replace $find, $replace | Add-Content -Path $tempFilePath; Remove ...
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($env:String) [Add-Content], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand

Move-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '$env' does not exist.
At line:1 char:289
+ ... -Path $filePath; Move-Item -Path $tempFilePath -Destination $filePath
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($env:String) [Move-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

The full command which is run in my bat file which produces the error above:

```
powershell -Command $filePath = 'filedir/file.conf.js'; "$tempFilePath = '$env:TEMP\$($filePath ^| Split-Path -Leaf)'"; $find = 'texttochange'; $replace = 'newtext'; (Get-Content -Path $filePath) -replace $find, $replace ^| Add-Content -Path $tempFilePath; Remove-Item -Path $filePath; Move-Item -Path $tempFilePath -Destination $filePath
```

The workaround that worked for me, I put all of my powershell commands in a ps1 file and called it from the bat file, this worked as below. Contents of the pshellfile.ps1 file:

```
$filePath = 'filedir/file.conf.js'
$tempFilePath = "$env:TEMP\$($filePath | Split-Path -Leaf)"
$find = 'texttochage'
$replace = 'newtext'
(Get-Content -Path $filePath) -replace $find, $replace | Add-Content -Path $tempFilePath
Remove-Item -Path $filePath
Move-Item -Path $tempFilePath -Destination $filePath
```

This is the command in my bat file:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File pshellfile.ps1
```

Comment: powershell -Command "$tempFilePath = '$env:TEMP\$($filePath ^| Split-Path -Leaf)'"

Comment: The command doesn't make sense to me! Where is `$filePath` defined? and surely even if it was defined, all you're doing is setting a variable inside powershell, then closing it, thus undefining the variable again!

Comment: Still the same outcome, same error. Thank you.

Comment: Have you copied my proposal exactely? I get no error at all.

Comment: I have copied it exactly have you tried it through a bat file. To give you the full picture this is the full command which works if i put directly in powershell. But does not when using the powershell -Command process in my bat file:          $filePath = 'filedir/file.conf.js'
>> $tempFilePath = "$env:TEMP\$($filePath | Split-Path -Leaf)"
>> $find = 'texttochange'
>> $replace = 'newtext'
>> (Get-Content -Path $filePath) -replace $find, $replace | Add-Content -Path $tempFilePath
>> Remove-Item -Path $filePath
>> Move-Item -Path $tempFilePath -Destination $filePath

Comment: strange - it's running in a batch file here without any problems. Try to use the full path name of the PowerShell.exe file: C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command …..

Comment: You cannot enter all of those `>>` characters like that on a single line of a batch file. I assume that they're supposed to represent new lines, so I have added them to your question on individual lines. Please in future do not post code into the comment area and expact it to be viewable in a format readable by us or the system if copied and pasted.

Comment: Apologies looks like i have made some progress with your advice, however i am now getting the error outlined in the code from the comment section?

Comment: You cannot run each line one by one with separate instances of `powershell.exe`. You could, possibly use semicolons, **`;`**, to separate individual commands, similar to how you used **`>>`** in your previous comment. At this time it is absolutely unclear what you're doing. Can you please post a correctly formatted example of your actual code in your question, including the `powershell -Command` part, we need to know exactly what your `.bat` file content looks like, and I suppose, why you're not just running a `.ps1` file. If we cannot replicate the issue, we cannot help you to fix it.

Comment: Hi thanks that is what i have done in the bat file. I just wanted to show the working outcome. if i copy and paste the one line command with the ; in it directly from the bat file into a command line it executes perfectly.

Comment: I have added it to the new error outlined section above.

Comment: Any luck replicating the issue? Thanks

Comment: Why did you modify the content from the comment, and you command line, you changed `$tempFilePath = '"$env:TEMP\$($filePath |` to `"$tempFilePath = '$env:TEMP\$($filePath ^|`. You could try this untested modification: `"%__AppDir__%powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command "$filePath = 'filedir/file.conf.js'; $tempFilePath = \"$env:TEMP\$($filePath | Split-Path -Leaf)\"; $find = 'texttochange'; $replace = 'newtext'; (Get-Content -Path $filePath) -replace $find, $replace | Add-Content -Path $tempFilePath; Remove-Item -Path $filePath; Move-Item -Path $tempFilePath -Destination $filePath"`.

Comment: I altered it upon advice from f6a4, which moved me on from the original error, to the new error. I have tried the untested modification you suggested, the cmd screen flashes very quickly up an disappears cannot see anything on the screen it is too quick and the change is not made. Trying to change one string in a conf.js file from a bat file cannot be this hard! very frustrating

Comment: Hi, Just to let anyone know i have used a work around. I placed the commands in a ps1 file and ran that through the bat file i have put the work around in the Question Area.

Comment: @dockerdev, add `&Pause` to the end if you want to see the results. Honestly, you asked for your command to be fixed, not for me to add to it. My impression was, from your [[tag:batch-file]] tag, that this was just one line of many, not the only one!

Answer (score 0):

WRT the initial question, getting the right magic in a cmd.exe line to run PowerShell can be frustrating.

```
SET "FILEPATH=C:\src\t\xxx.txt"
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Join-Path $($Env:TEMP) $('%FILEPATH%' | Split-Path -Leaf)"
```

Produces:

```
C:\Users\lit\AppData\Local\Temp\xxx.txt
```